# Clean store in between find operations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I do the following request:

```
App.Phones.find({'country' : 'DE'});
```

My backend replies with some telephone numbers. Now I do:

```
App.Phones.find({'country' : 'ES'});
```

Now I get other telephone numbers. But:

```
App.Phones.all();
```

Has accumulated the "old" numbers and the new ones. Is it possible to clean the store between calls to find? How?

I have tried with `App.Phones.clean();`, without success (`has no method 'clean'`)

### EDIT

This is quite strange but: calling `record.destroy();` (as suggested by intuitivepixel) on an object does not remove it from the store, it just marks it as `destroyed=true`. That means, the drop-down is still showing that option. Actually, walking the records (`all()`) shows that the records are still there after being destroyed. Maybe Ember will remove them from the store eventually, but that does not help me at all: since my select is bound to `all()`, I need them to be removed right now.

Even worse: since the object is there, but destroyed, the select shows it, but it does not allow to select it!

I can think of a very ugly hack where I create an `Ember.A` with filtered records (removing the `destroy`ed records), like this:

1. Destroy all records (the old ones)
2. Request new records from the backend
3. When the records are received (`.then`), walk the records in the store (`.all()`), that is, the destroyed and the new ones.
4. Add the records in the array which are not `destroy`ed
5. Bind the select to this filtered array.

This looks extremely ugly, and I am really surprised that Ember is not able to just fully and reliably clean the store for a certain record type.

Comment: just updated my answer, maybe you find the workaround usefull.

Comment: @intuitivepixel: updated my question with my findings. Does not look good at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do the following to *clean* the in the store saved `Phones` records:

```
App.Phones.find({}); //this will invalidate your cache
```

But obviously this will make a new request retrieving all the phone numbers.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could use `find()` in the application route, then either `all()` or a `filter()` in other routes to retrieve just `DE`, `ES` etc. In other words there is no such method available to do something like: `App.Phones.clean()`.

### Update

Another way (manually) I can think of to remove the records of one type from the cache could be to delete them one by one beetwen your `find()` operations, for example create a simple utility function which contains the below code, and call it beetwen your calls to `find()`:

```
App.Phones.all().forEach(function(record) {
  record.destroy();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have just discovered that `destroy` has a very inconvenient side effect: it is not possible to reload destroyed records. That is, for example: you get some phones for Berlin, then switch to Bremen, and then switch back to Berlin; in that case, the Berlin records are not loaded anymore, because they have been destroyed before. I think the right approach is to do unloadRecord, but I have trouble doing an unloadRecord in a live array (`all()`)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the (unsatisfying, ugly, hacky, non-intuitive) code that I have come up with. It is doing the job, but I have a very bad feeling about this:

```
getNewPhones : function (countryCode, subtype, city) {
    // Mark old records as destroyed
    App.Availablephone.all().forEach(function(phone, index) {
        phone.destroy();
        console.log('Destroyed phone %o', phone);
    });
    // Not possible to set the availablePhones to .all(), because old records are still there
    //App.Availablephone.find({country : countryCode, subtype : subtype, city : city});
    //this.set('availablePhones', App.Availablephone.all());
    // So, hack is in order:
    //   1. request new data
    //   2. filter all records to just get the newly received ones (!!!)
    var _this = this;
    App.Availablephone.find({country : countryCode, subtype : subtype, city : city}).then(function(recordArray) {
        var availablePhones = Ember.A();
        App.Availablephone.all().forEach(function(phone, index) {
            if(!phone.isDestroyed) {
                console.log('Adding phone=%o', phone);
                availablePhones.push(phone);
            }
        });
        _this.set('availablePhones', availablePhones);
    });
},
```

Comments / critiques / improvements suggestions are very much welcome!